# Category with multiple classes/types/labelled morphisms?

Tags: category-theory, diagram-chasing

Is there a notion of a category with "labelled" or "typed" morphisms?

I imagine that each morphism would belong to a certain class/type, and those classes would form a commutative monoid under composition of the associated morphisms.

As an example, in the category of people and their possessions, this diagram commutes
[image: example]
with the rules
$owns\circ is = is \circ owns = owns$
$owns \circ owns = owns$
$is \circ is = is$

Neither `is` nor `owns` is obviously functorial, and it seems that the diagram with labelled morphisms is more informative than separate categories for `is` and `owns`, together with a mapping of objects between the two.

(It's also fun to note that this seemingly lets us derive $2^2=4$ distinct "arrow categories", each of which is semantically somewhat meaningful)

This notion does not seem well documented - I couldn't find anything on nlab, at least. Is it inconsistent, less interesting than I expected, or are there better formulations of the same idea?

Comment: This sounds a bit like *double categories*.

Comment: It is relatively common to talk about *classes of morphisms* (often closed under identities, composition, perhaps isomorphism). See, for instance, [factorisation systems](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/factorization+system) and [model categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+category).